# Where can I place the code "save to database", which is located in the controller

Tags: symfony

I would like to reduce the controller in accordance with the philosophy of "symfony". Maybe I need to use the services, or have anything to standard?

Here's my function

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
...
/**
 * @Route("/save", name="save")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @return Response
 */
public function saveAction()
{
    //returns an array of users on this date
    //array(
    //    "Kate" => 18,
    //    "John" => 24,
    //    "Albert" => 31,
    //);
    $users= $this->get("users")->users();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $checkNow = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(array("date" => $this->nowDate));

    if(null === $checkNow) {
        foreach($users as $name => $qty) {
            $userDB = new User();
            $userDB->setDate($this->nowDate);
            $userDB->setQty($qty);
            $userDB->setName($name);
            $em->persist($userDB);
        }

        $em->flush();
    }

    return new Response("New users are added");
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You better go through some examples in here: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony

Comment: BentCoder Thank you for link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony is just a framework and allows anything, but generally database related stuff is done inside an EntityRepository. I usually keep EntityRepositories for complex queries or database operations.

You can have a service to keep your controllers lean, like so:

Sample controller action:

```
$users= $this->get("users")->users();
$userService = $this->get('user.service');

if (!$userService->hasUsersCreatedOn($this->nowDate) {
    $userService->createMultiple($users);
}

return 'message';
```

Sample user service:

```
public function createMultiple($users); // just loops through each and creates

public function create($name, $qty, $date) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setDate($this->nowDate);
    $user->setQty($qty);
    $user->setName($name);

    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    $this->entityManager->flush($user);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: mickadoo Thank for your help

Comment: @user3771955 No problem (usually people upvote / accept helpful answers)